# change join condition depending on row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I want to do an inner join (merge) with `df1`:

```
mandant fk_lart_nr  fk_ust_sch
7   55  43
00  55  43
```

and `df2`:

```
mandant ust_sch ust_bez
0   59  Gutschrift 19 %                                                                           
18  3   Rechnung 0 %
```

I want to use two join conditions. The first one is always fixed.

first join condition is fixed `df1.fk_ust_sch = df2.ust_sch`

However, the second join condition should be used depending on what is the value of df1.mandant.

1. if df1.mandant is either 7 or 18 ( .isin([7,18]) ), the second join condition should be this:

`df1.mandant = df2.mandant`

2. If df1.mandant is not 7 or 18, the second join condition should be this using df2:
   `df2.mandant == '00'`

```
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['fk_ust_sch'],
                                        right_on=['ust_sch'],
                                        how='inner', suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))
```

Comment: There is confusion whether your `mandant` field is integer or string.  You used `.isin([7,18])` implying it is integer type.  But then compare `df2.mandant` with `'00'`, implying it is sting type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot specify join condition during `.merge()`, what you could do is to filter the merge result with your required conditions, as follows:

**Case 1: If your `mandant` fields are of integer type:**

```
# Reuse your codes for merge
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on='fk_ust_sch',
                           right_on='ust_sch',
                           how='inner', suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))

# Filter
m1 = df_merged.mandant_df1.isin([7,18]) & (df_merged.mandant_df1 == df_merged.mandant_df2)
m2 = ~df_merged.mandant_df1.isin([7,18]) & (df_merged.mandant_df2 == 0)  ## use 0 instead of '00'

df_merged_filtered = df_merged.loc[m1 | m2]
```

**Case 2: If your `mandant` fields are of string type:**

```
# Reuse your codes for merge
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on='fk_ust_sch',
                           right_on='ust_sch',
                           how='inner', suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))

# Filter
### Put 7, 18 in quotes as '7', '18'
m1 = df_merged.mandant_df1.isin(['7','18']) & (df_merged.mandant_df1 == df_merged.mandant_df2)
m2 = ~df_merged.mandant_df1.isin(['7','18']) & (df_merged.mandant_df2 == '00')

df_merged_filtered = df_merged.loc[m1 | m2]
```

**Demo**

Enriched your sample data in order to include all required test cases:

(Demo using case 1 with your `mandant` fields as integer type)

**Input Data**

```
df1

   mandant  fk_lart_nr  fk_ust_sch
0        7          55          43
1        0          55          43
2       10          55          43


df2

   mandant  ust_sch          ust_bez
0        0       59  Gutschrift 19 %
1        6       43  Gutschrift 21 %
2        7       43  Gutschrift 30 %
3        0       43  Gutschrift 50 %
4       18        3     Rechnung 0 %
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_merged_filtered)

   mandant_df1  fk_lart_nr  fk_ust_sch  mandant_df2  ust_sch          ust_bez
1            7          55          43            7       43  Gutschrift 30 %
5            0          55          43            0       43  Gutschrift 50 %
8           10          55          43            0       43  Gutschrift 50 %
```